# How to find nested class arrow in staruml 5.0?

Tags: uml, inner-classes, class-diagram, staruml

I use staruml 5.0.2.1570. because I don't like modern web uml diagram editor.

I want to use express nested class. but I can't find the arrow to express it.
But I found someone used it like below one. Where can I find it ?

[image]

Comment: You need to delete the last two questions or you risk this being closed for being off-top. Pls. read the help about which questions you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

The nested class can be found in the Toolbox under the section `Package`.  It's called `Containment`. You can draw your nested classes:

[image]

As you will notice, StarUML shows the nesting in the Model explorer, as soon as you have modeled the containment.

The reason to show containment under the package section is routed in the UML specification (7.4.4):

> Conforming tools may optionally allow the “circle-plus” notation defined in sub clause 12.2.4 to show Package
> membership to also be used to show membership in other kinds of Namespaces (for example, to show nestedClassifiers
> and ownedBehaviors of Classes).

Comment: Cool. I'd wish that silly EA would handle it like that.

Comment: @qwerty_so The model explorer is indeed a cool thing.  It's not without reason that StarUML is Graddy Booch's favourite tool.

Comment: Tried to import OMG's metamodel but that did throw an exception. Else it looks like a handy tool. Will tinker a bit :-)